# Visualforce page taking too long time to load in Salesforce1 App

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

We have a Salesforce1 App, everything is fine except one frequent complain from users that app is taking almost 60 seconds to display landing page and displays the white screen until then on ipad.
To verify if our app has a problem we created another sample salesforce1 app having a single visualforce welcome page. I observed same problem here. Visualforce page taking long time(approx 60 seconds) to load at first time when login with salesforce1 app on ipad.There after it is loaded fast within second. Any suggestion how to make it faster. I have also tried it with blank page mean without controller as below.

```
 <apex:page docType="html-5.0" sidebar="false" cache="true">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
</apex:page>
```

But it also take 60 seconds to load at first time.
Appreciate any help resolving this issue or any comments.

Comment: why `cache="true"` any specific reason?

Comment: For the cache page no any other reason..

Comment: I have used it on other pages also any issue with this?